# How to make my own sequence of numbers and letters in a seven segment display circuit?

Tags: led, encoder, decoder

In this circuit, I have connected a single switch to a priority encoder, which is then connected to some inverters, further connected to a binary decoder, then to some current limiting resistor which is attached to 7 LEDs.

I'm trying to make it so that the LEDs light up in a sequence of numbers and letters.

I'm pretty sure the layout of my circuit is alright. I just don't know how to use the decoder to get my own sequence of numbers or letters whenever I press the switch.

If anyone could help tell me how that's done or if you think my circuits wrong, I'd be really grateful to know!

[image]

Comment: _»I'm pretty sure the layout of my circuit is alright.«_ Well, I'm not, since you connected some outputs to ground, the LED connections seem to be a total mess, and U4 is the wrong item for your purpose as you don't want only one output to be low at a time...

Comment: I don't think this will work the way you want it to. Your LED part is a huge mess. You're going to short circuit a lot of those LEDs because you're not grounding it properly. Refer to [this picture](https://www.elprocus.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/configuration.jpg) if you want to see how you can properly look up your LEDs.

Comment: Thanks for the picture on grounding LEDs. How would you then connect the to resistors? Would it be that when a goes to a, that would be where you attach the first resistor? Or have I got that wrong?

Comment: What would you suggest if not U4? I was wanting to recreate the decoder using discrete logic to then give me my own sequence of numbers and letters? How would you suggest to do this?

Comment: I also wasn't sure how to connect d in U2 to my circuit?

Comment: Throws random circuit on web and expects it to do something.  Your circuit will not do what you want.  Aside from this you have fundamental problems.  You have 5 grounds and 4 of them are connected to outputs.  Odds are you will fry all chips when you apply power.  The use of LS138 will allow you to light one segment.  TTL inputs float high, but you need pull-up resistors.  U2 will output 1001 when switch is pushed.

Comment: I was told I couldn't use pull up resistance in this simulation. I had to use current limiting resistors. This was all done on NI Multisim by the way.

Comment: "my own sequence of numbers or letters" implies something arbitrary which implies a custom ROM, or in any reasonably sane implementation, software on an MCU.

Comment: I have to creat the letters 3, g, n, s, a, i, s, l in a sequence by creating my own custom BCD using discrete logic. I was not taught how to do that so I'm not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm pretty sure the layout of my circuit is alright.

I'd suggest NO, you have absolutely no clue if your circuit is functional. There is so much wrong with it it's hard to know where to start, so I'll go left to right in your schematic.

1. Read the datasheet for the 74147. It is a priority encoder, it derives the highest value signal from the inputs.
   [image]

   -In your case only the condition of input 9 has any relevance. You won't get a series of outputs as you think.
   -You don't ground outputs you don't need ...you have grounded output "D"
   -You have no pullup in the input switch. It would still work but is bad practice, get used to defining the states.
2. U3A, you have an output grounded.
3. U4, You have an output grounded.

   - Only signals A,B have a chance of working since input C is grounded.
4. The display LEDs appear to be simply 7 individual LEDS.

   - Seven segment displays come as either Common Anode or Common Cathode. It would be a benefit to you to consider this configuration when working out your solution. What you have simply does not work.

[image]

[image]

As an example of what does not work in your display section, you have Y0, Y1, Y2 and Y6 output resistors all connected to ground. You also have Y7 connected to ground.

Back to the drawing board and try again. I'd suggest the almost any tutorial on using an LED seven segment display would be worth reading.

To start the learning process off I:

1. I suggest you start with a 74LS04 and a single LED. Understand what the output circuit looks like and understand what logic HI and Lo mean.

[image]

2. Look into using this invertor to drive a single LED ON/OFF with a series resistor to limit the LED current. Decide whether you want the LED ON for the output when Hi or Lo and discover the changes required to support this.
3. Try to use the 74LS138 to drive 7 LEDs. Activate the inputs A,B,C and see if you can get more than one LED to light (hint: you can't) with this decoder.
4. Have a look at the 74LS47 and see whether you can figure out how to drive the LEDs (hint: this is no open Collector drive so there are circuit restrictions).
5. Once you can drive 7 LEDs based on a BCD input, you are partly there. Now you need to consider how you would generate the BCD inputs required based on a single push button input.

Comment: With my grounded d output in my encoder or do I leave it blank? Also, why has only input 9 got any relevance? I don't know what you mean by that?

Comment: What do you mean by defining states? and what should I do with all the other outputs that I shouldn't have grounded?

Comment: If you don't know what defined states are, then you probably should not be tackling any logic problems. If you don't know how TTL logic drive high and low outputs you should probably not be connecting any chips together to form a circuit (you are likely to damage them).

Comment: Ah, no, am ok with basic truth tables and gates, it is just putting it together to form my own decoder that I'm having a bit of trouble with.